# How do I open an Access 97 data file using Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access, dbase

I need to read the data in an **Access 97** file that has about 400K records.

I would like to use either **TurboDelphi Pro** or **dBASE SE**.

I only have **Access 2003**. What is the easiest way of proceeding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to go with TurboDelphi, you can use the ADOConnection component on the [dbGo tab](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbGo_Overview).

When you Configure the connection string, use the Jet driver and point to your .mdb file.  Then use the [ADO controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbGo_Controls) to get at the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifically familiar with TurboDelphi Pro or dBASE SE, but with Delphi / C++ Builder you can open the tables using an ODBC connection.

Create an ODBC DSN in Administrative Tools / Data Sources.  Then, you should be able to use data objects in your project to open the tables and access the data.

Comment: Do you mean in the BDE Administrator?

Comment: You create the ODBC DSN in Windows, under Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Data Sources (ODBC).  Once the DSN is created, then you can open the database using the BDE Administrator and can also connect data components within the IDE.

Comment: Once you have the DSN created and working I'd strongly suggest going DSN less.   
Using DSN-Less Connections
http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html
ODBC DSN-Less Connection Tutorial Part I
http://www.amazecreations.com/datafast/GetFile.aspx?file=ODBCTutor01.htm&Article=true
HOWTO: Use "DSN-Less" ODBC Connections with RDO and DAO
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=147875
ODBC DSN Less
http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81